# Trying to synchronise .load() in jQuery -- not working

Tags: jquery

For a photogalery I load a file (via ajax) which returns an array of src's of the images I want to display. They HAVE TO be displayed in the exact order the ajax call returns.

I'm using a for-loop with the `.load()` function inside it, but that way it's not synchronised. If I output the value of i inside the `.load()` function, it doesn't go 0, 1, 3, 4, etc. but 0, 3, 2, 4, etc.

The simplified version of my code:

```
$.get('photostack.php', {album_name:album_name} , function(data) {
var items_count = data.length;
for(var i = 0; i < items_count; ++i){
    var item_source = data[i];
    var cnt = 0;
    $('<img />').load(function(){
        var $image = $(this);
        ++cnt;
        console.log(i);
        $ps_container.append($image);
    }).attr('src',item_source).attr('class',i);
}
},'json');
```

`console.log(i)` now gives the wrong order. It should be perfectly ascending.

I have tried a lot of things. Delaying every load 100 ms, using an object as variable for `cnt`/`i`, etc. but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I really get it, but maybe something like this will work:

```
$.get('photostack.php', {album_name:album_name} , function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var image = new Image();
            image.src = data[i];
            image.className = i;
            image.style.display = 'none';
        $(image).appendTo($ps_container).load(function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    }
},'json');​
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of async nature of `.load`. You can't predict when callback function will be called. To sync them use [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Comment: Plz help, for detail, how to sync it? I have another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928295/sync-image-load-in-javascript

Comment: You cannot sync it in a valid manner. Redesign your code for async routine.

Comment: When i wrote sync, i mean 100 async operations to be synced, with single callback.