# Synchronous image loading in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm writing a JavaScript function:

```
function imgstr(url) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
}
```

The target is to output a base64 string from a given image URL.

While the above code doesn't work, the reason being that after `img src` gets assigned by a URL, it loads the image content *asynchronously*. What can be done to make this procedure *synchronous*?

Comment: Use img.onload() funtion

Comment: @Anto King yes, I know it, but that's not sync, I must return the value in the outer function body!

Answer (score -1):

Use below method that will wait till thge image to load

```
    currentimage.onload = function(e){
    // code, runned after image load
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: That's async, I want sync!